# How to collect site information having it different links?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm developing a web crawler in python and I'm using Scrapy. For this web crawler i need to fo a site and this contains the main page of the ad and a sub page that I need to access to get the information. How do I do that ?
So far I have developed the code that I will post below. What can I implement more so that this one goes to the main page, takes the information, goes to "sub page" to take information and returns to the main page again to take information of other announcements?
Thanks.

Code:

```
import scrapy


class SapoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "imo"
 start_urls = [
    'https://www.imovirtual.com/comprar/apartamento/lisboa/'
 ]

 def parse(self, response):
     for Property in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
         yield {
            'preco': Property.css('span.offer-item 
title::text').extract_first(),
            'author': Property.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
            'data': Property.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
            'data': Property.css('li.offer-item-price-per- 
m::text').extract(),
 }

    next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that (pseudo code)

```
def parse(self, response):
     for Property in response.css('div.offer-item-details'):
         youritem = {
            'preco': Property.css('span.offer-item title::text').extract_first(),
            'author': Property.css('li.offer-item-price::text').extract(),
            'data': Property.css('li.offer-item-area::text').extract(),
            'data': Property.css('li.offer-item-price-perm::text').extract(),
         }

         # extract the sub page link
         # load and parse it
         yield scrapy.Request(subpage_link, callback=self.parse_subpage)

    next_page = response.css('li.pager-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)

 def parse_subpage(self, youritem):
     # here parse your subpage
     # and complete your item information
        yield youritem
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :)
What should I put in the parse_subpage function? the sub page link?